# Can we run Zend framework 2.0.5 or 2.x.x version on PHP 7.3 or any latest version?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

My Zend framework version is 2.0.5

In the original project, I hope to be able to easily use the php 7.3 version

Zend framework 2.0.5 or 2.x.x supports php 7.3?

or upgrate zf3?

Comment: I think you can easily find Zend versions support with PHP versions by googling it.

Comment: @Mtxz I did search some posts, there are some problems when using 7's zf2, but it's not clear at the moment, and zf2 was released before php7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the fact that ZF 2.* is deprecated since 2018, your version (2.0.5) is **NINE YEARS OLD**

I'd be more concerned about using such an old version, rather than be concerned if it is compatible with PHP 7.3.

Using PHP 7.3 is (afaik) possible, but maybe you'll need to make just few edits in your code (and in the library) for specific usecases.

Howevery, I'll suggest you to upgrade to zf3 as soon as possible.

Comment: I am entangled in how much energy I spend, thank you for correcting my important concepts, now I will directly promote to zf3

Answer (score 2):

Yes it works with no problem.
your php version is compatible with zf2, i have php 7.4.11 it works with no problem with zYes it works with no problem.